# how to fix semantic issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to fix an issue in my app which causes it to crash on the iPhone 5s.

The issue comes from this line of code specifically

```
 imagePicker.delegate = self;
```

The warning reads exactly this

"Assigning to 'id'from incompatible type 'ShowcaseFilterListController*const_strong'

This is the entire Image picker method

```
-(IBAction)segmentAction:(id)sender
```

{

```
segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
{
    isStatic = NO;

}
else if (segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)
{

    isStatic = YES;

    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceType   soureType;

    soureType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    imagePicker.sourceType = soureType;

}
```

}

I am using GPUImage and still learning, The app works well besides this one issue. And my apologies if it is a small or stupid mistake :)

Thanks everyone

Comment: Does ShowcaseFilterListController implement UIImagePickerControllerDelegate?

Comment: Make sure that your `ShowcaseFilterListController` implements the delegate protocol.

Comment: The delegate for UIImagePickerController is of type `id<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>`. Please make sure ShowcaseFilterListController includes these protocol references in its header, so that the interface declaration looks like, `@interface ShowcaseFilterListController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just going to expand on the comments here... You have to be sure to make sure that you're class conforms to the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, and the UINavigationControllerDelegate in order for this to work. Your @interface should look something like this:

```
@interface ShowcaseFilterListController () < UINavigationControllerDelegate , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate >
```

Then, if you check out the [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html), you'll find info on the delegate methods that you'll want to implement.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
```

Comment: Alright thanks for all the answers :) have fixed the @interface so its now as suggested above, I implemented them and its still crashing on 64 bit devices... I will keep looking at it but there are no more warnings/ errors..

Comment: @user2597023 Glad to hear it, and I'm not sure how to solve that, it might have to be your next question, and if this answer solved the current problem please don't forget to mark it as correct by clicking the "check mark" next to it. :)

Comment: well, I changed a few things from google recommendations also and now its working on the 64 bit simulator! :D testing it on device now and will let you know if it works on there :)  Thanks for the help  Alright now It is working but another issue has come up.. This issue is solved and I will try to solve the other myself and will ask another question if I can't get it, Thanks again :)